# Overcoming Issues When Downloading a CSV File for Parsing. Linux vs Windows New Line Charachter

Tags: c++, linux, windows, csv, delimiter

I am attempting to analyze stock data using historical Stock prices. This data can be downloaded from Yahoo Finance(https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL) as a CSV file. However when I download the file it is organized as one line and not separated by a new line at the end of each row. I have read that this is because different OS uses different characters to denote new lines. Are there ways to overcome this issue when downloading a file or in a text editor, or should I modify my code to accommodate the format the files are downloaded in. I am coding in C++ on Windows 10 and viewing files in NotePad. (Im also new to StackOverFlow so advice on asking questions is appreciated.)

Example:
How the code should be

2017-10-16,157.899994,160.000000,157.649994,159.880005,159.307312,24121500

2017-10-17,159.779999,160.869995,159.229996,160.470001,159.895203,18997300

2017-10-18,160.419998,160.710007,159.600006,159.759995,159.187729,16374200

2017-10-19,156.750000,157.080002,155.020004,155.979996,155.421280,42584200

2017-10-20,156.610001,157.750000,155.960007,156.250000,155.690308,23974100

How it is downloaded

2017-10-16,157.899994,160.000000,157.649994,159.880005,159.307312,241215002017-10-17,159.779999,160.869995,159.229996,160.470001,159.895203,189973002017-10-18,160.419998,160.710007,159.600006,159.759995,159.187729,163742002017-10-19,156.750000,157.080002,155.020004,155.979996,155.421280,425842002017-10-20,156.610001,157.750000,155.960007,156.250000,155.690308,23974100

my code to read in the file

```
void Stock::readData(filename){
ifstream stream;
stream.open(fileName);

if(stream.fail()){
    cout << "The file " << fileName <<" failed to open." << endl;
    return;
}


string line ="";
cout << line << endl;

while(!stream.eof()){

   // cout << '*' << endl;
    getline(stream,line);
   //cout << line << endl;

    string parsed[7];

    int num = Spliter(line, ',', parsed, 7);

    string tempDate;
    float tempOpen;
    float tempHigh;
    float tempLow;
    float tempClose;
    float tempCloseAdj;
    float tempVolume;

    /*for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        cout << parsed[i] << endl;
   }*/

    tempDate = parsed[0];
    tempOpen = stof(parsed[1]);
    tempHigh = stof(parsed[2]);
    tempLow = stof(parsed[3]);
    tempClose = stof(parsed[4]);
    tempCloseAdj = stof(parsed[5]);
    tempVolume = stof(parsed[6]);


/*
    cout <<(tempDate) << " ";
    cout << (tempOpen)<< " ";
    cout << (tempHigh)<< " ";
    cout << (tempLow)<< " ";
    cout << (tempClose)<< " ";
    cout << tempCloseAdj<< " ";
    cout << (tempVolume) << endl;
*/

    vector<float> v;

    dates.push_back(tempDate);
    data.push_back(v);
    data[numberOfDays].push_back(tempOpen);
    data[numberOfDays].push_back(tempHigh);
    data[numberOfDays].push_back(tempLow);
    data[numberOfDays].push_back(tempClose);
    data[numberOfDays].push_back(tempCloseAdj);
    data[numberOfDays].push_back(tempVolume);
   // cout << '#' << endl;

    numberOfDays++;
}

stream.close();
```

}

Comment: Where is your code snippet? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Would you please provide a code which runs independent of any header? where does `Spliter` come from? If the code does contains `#include`s, a main function, etc, that will be even better. A working example with the lowest possible number of lines which has the same problem makes your question more attractive and pleasant to read.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. In order to convert the EOL line endings between platforms like Mac, Windoxs or Unix download a text editor such as Notepad++. Open the file in notepadd++ and go to the edit tab. Find the EOL COnversion button and use it to convert the file.